# Gwt change image size in ImageCell

Tags: image, gwt, image-size, celltable

I create a small CellTable with gwt. In that table I would like to add some images.
For this I use following code:

```
Column<Company, String> columnflag = new Column<Company, String>(new ImageCell()) {
    public String getValue(Company company) {
        return company.getImageSmall();
    }
  };
```

This works fine. But I would like to change the size of the image? Does anyone know how I could do this? I have nothing found... Set a fix column width and height does not help.

Greetz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
ImageCell imageCell = new ImageCell() {
    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        super.render(context, value, sb);
        String imagePath = "images/yourImage.png";
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<img src = '"+imagePath+"' height = '20px' width = '20px' />");

    }
};
Column<Company, String> columnflag = new Column<Company, String>(imageCell) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(Form object) {
            return "";
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay, that works very well, but how could I pass the `imagePath` to the `render` method?

Comment: Well, actually that solution is a little bit tricky. There will be added two `<img>` one is empty and the other contain the image. The useless <img> switch the other image. Also it is not possible to pass a dynamic value for `imagePath`, or?
Is there another solution?

Comment: @Taz, Do you want to display images based on different Companies? If you want to do that then in render() method you can get Company object with the help of context.getKey(). Context.getKey() will provide you Company object, from that you can get images.

Comment: Exactly that is what I want to do. Works great. Thanks everyone!